# Define a python function based on previously defined function specifying argument

Tags: python

I have one defined function and I would like to define another one which is exactly the same as the first, but specifying one parameter.

One possible way of doing that is

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

def my_function_foo(arg1):
    return(my_function(arg1, 'bar'))


>>> my_function_foo('foo')
foo bar
```

But I suppose there is a cleaner way, closer to:

```
my_function_foo = my_function(arg2 = 'foo')
```

Comment: Won’t def my_function(arg1, arg2='bar'):... do?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel You might want several functions, one that assumes a value of `bar` for `arg2`, one that assumes a value of `3`, etc.

Comment: Ah! This calls for decorators;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `functools.partial`:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> my_function_foo = partial(my_function, arg2='bar')
>>> my_function_foo('foo')
foo bar
```

Note that `my_function_foo` is not technically a `function`, but an instance of `partial`. Calling the instance calls the underlying function using the previously given and current arguments merged in the expected way.

Comment: Awesome! Learned something today ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a decorator that will pass the parameter for you.

```
from functools import wraps

def give_param(param='bar'):
    def inner_function(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            return func(*args, arg2=param)

        return wrapper

    return inner_function

@give_param('bar')
def my_function(arg1,arg2):
    # do some stuff
    print(arg1,arg2)
```

So if you want arg2 = 3,

```
@give_param(3)
def my_function(arg1,arg2):
    # do some stuff
    print(arg1,arg2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might solve your problem with an inner function as follows:

```
def my_function(arg1, arg2='bar'):
    def my_function_foo(arg1):
        print(arg1, arg2)
    return my_function_foo(arg1)

my_function(arg1 = 'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the multiple dispatch library to do a method override like in C:

```
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(object, object)
def my_function(arg1, arg2):
    print(arg1, arg2)

@dispatch(object)
def my_function(arg1):
    return(my_function(arg1, 'bar'))

my_function('foo')
my_function('foo', 'foo')
```